# fill table with vue js 3 and composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, composable

i´m trying to fill table with data from my API developed with laravel 9.52. i´m using composition API and composable, to build all my logic. All run ok, when i clicked my button in my form, call a function from my composable that receive data from my function and sen petition to mi API, this, return:

```
Proxy(Array) {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}, 6: {…}, 7: {…}, 8: {…}, 9: {…}, 10: {…}, 11: {…}, 12: {…}, 13: {…}, …}
```

all my data ok. this data, i´m trying to send my table through props in my principal component, add all my script code in principal component:

```
<script>
import { onMounted, defineComponent, ref, toRef, reactive } from 'vue';

import useNregister from '../../composables/ncalls'
import asignedCalls from './asignedCalls';
import nAsignedCalls from './nasignedCalls';

export default {
    name: "actionForm",
    components: { asignedCalls, nAsignedCalls },
           
    setup(context) {

        const { getRegisters, deleteCalls, queryForKeywords, getResults, getItems } = useNregister()
        var param_search = {};
        var registerData = /*reactive([]);*/ref([])

        
        async function searchRegisters(){
            var address = "";
            var city = "";
            var cp = "";

            address = document.getElementById("address").value
            if( address != "" ) {
                param_search["parameter"] = "address";
                param_search["value"] = address;
            }

            city = document.getElementById("city").value
            if( city != "" ) {
                param_search["parameter"] = "city";
                param_search["value"] = city;
            }

            cp = document.getElementById("postal_code").value
            if( cp != "" ) {
                param_search["parameter"] = "cp";
                param_search["value"] = cp
            }

            registerData.value = await getRegisters( toRef(param_search,'param_search') );
            console.log(registerData.value)
        }

        return { 
            searchRegisters,
            registerData
        }
    }
}
```

and this ref it´s filled in my function with:

```
registerData.value = await getRegisters( toRef(param_search,'param_search') );
```

this function it´s async:

```
 async function searchRegisters(){
```

and i call it in my button:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-dark" value="Buscar registros" @click="searchRegisters()">
```

`searchRegister` call to my function composable that return data:

```
export default function useNregister(){
    var registers = ref()
    var param_search = ref([])
    var pagination = ref([])

    const getRegisters = async (param_search) => {
        var keys = Object.values(param_search);
        
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("parameter", keys[0].parameter); 
        formData.append("value", keys[0].value); 
        return await axios.post('/api/listingApi/getRegister', formData, {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'})
            .then((res) => {
                return registers.value = res.data.data
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });  

    }
```

and return data in my composable:

```
return{
        getRegisters,
        registers,
    }
```

when i received my data and assigned to my ref, i´m retuning this `ref` in `return[]`:

```
return { 
    searchRegisters,
    registerData
}
```

I´m including my table component send it this array:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade-in active" id="nasigned">
   <div id="app5">
      <nAsignedCalls :register-data="registerData"></nAsignedCalls> 
   </div>
</div>
```

and in `nAsignedCalls` i have a `definition props` and `v-for` to fill my table:

```
<template v-for="item in registerData" :key='item'>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ (item.name) ? item.name : '' }} </td>
                    <td>{{ (item.address) ? item.address : ''}}</td>
                    <td>{{ (item.province) ? item.province : ''}} </td>
                    <td>{{ (item.city) ? item.city : ''}} </td>
  ............
```

and my script:

```
export default defineComponent({
        name: 'nAsignedCalls',    
        /*data(){
            return{
                items: [],
                    pagination: {
                        current_page: 1,
                    },
            }
        },*/
        props: { 
            registerData: {
                type: Array,
                //default: () => ([])
            } 
        },

        /*setup() {
            const { deleteCalls, queryForKeywords, getResults, getItems } = useNregister() 
            
            function remove(id) {
                deleteDates(id)
            }
            
            function searchId(action) {
                let id = document.getElementsByClassName('id_search')[0].value
                const params = [action, id];
                
                queryForKeywords(params)
            }

            function searchName(action) {
                let id = document.getElementsByClassName('name_search')[0].value
                const params = [action, id];
                
                queryForKeywords(params)
            }

            function searchPhone(action) {
                let id = document.getElementsByClassName('phone_search')[0].value
                const params = [action, id];
                
                queryForKeywords(params)
            }

            function edit(action) {
                window.location.href = '/roomboss/calls/'+action+"/edit";
            }


            function getPage(page){
                getItems(page);
            }

            return { 
                remove,
                searchId,
                searchName,
                searchPhone,
                edit,
                getResults,
                getPage,
            }
        }*/
    });
```

i have all my code comment because i need fill my table. When i get it, i continue with next functions.

My question it´s. What i´m doing wrong for my data my data does not arrive to my table. in my ref `var registerData = ref([])` i trayed with `reactive([])` and same problem... I hope anybody can help me and say that i´m doing bad

[SFC EXAMPLE](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNrtW+ty28YVfpUN0w4pmyASp26ntKRUvnTG06nryeSf6XFWwJKEDWKRxVISR6OH6c/+zgN0pn6xfmcXl8WNhBy5tSfWJDKw2D17ztmz567r0Vmazi62YjQfHWeBilJ9ukiiTSqVZkupNj+KWGy4eid0lKzYUskNG8/81hcCMX5Urkx4Fq0SET7hcZyVq5IzZ7RYsUgCmWSa8TT9jp2wQAmuBZCaXC8Shp9AAmQiEp3N8xH6aSFgP90skpujRUKwZhu5TfRk/DW9jDFY2+rh8K1qWOfbTMt9Hrr7PKR9jv2cj6PpyLLD2/B09jaTCZhsAC/yD9liNGf5VosRGELvi9Fa6zSb+362DIhLb7OZVCsfTzOFraKNmIls450reZkJBcCLEfApYfgYvBDKUyIJhRJqH8zG1BZcAks8BSmdR05So8UmjcFIyA3hcBxGFyyIeZadLEbgt+ZRIhTbaO87dr7yLteRFixb81BeMgXWhSJkqffdYpSvb8EAOuztNtPRcucRPJyPl2kOKQPMP9TWdewfe5vQ+yPbxI0tOqcTjd4KWKWdcwehFuAXMb1nvYGRgY+Brm9L65WMFyNcno3AqMYkmQrFtQQ4FoWNsTcWCj6B/YFYyxhniDl0SGZOKBXfi4fBRaY6kglbR2EoktPa4mPfftxHCkSIsOjjlg92dXG9Y7w51nofJhQ8xm31IGSbLD+L4XLSntUtIgS9X0KiJN1qpnepPcUrOqL8THkYKpHhYtnjrF6V+HkbKRH2wYz5uYhJ67mrTp9iSRBE73+B0jEzPpDV/zd+BJHeFczIn2/DCbvk9Em0DXn4ubIAusYyIJWQ4PhNIEPYgVvxobby9Mn7X8JoJdlLM/rr2HLrS9ij/uocON9qLRMQWUA61wnD/14I44LhCx5vad7jbRZwBVasogzKkS7KX4I4Ct7hWya4CtY/mE9CZZOjugVx8K49f5h1ggG9CyZ0yNe3D7oFbBuXMxN+AWG58NKIHJBeGYsjd8V+gTQLeG1+HCXvGA90dEHSF3LNPS1Xq9hILD/H2FqJJV6+Lpw7QH8hmXnhIc+Ofd5rBeLoI2J9AN0KW+PIfRCqx/62eYMGKJBcuoBLpncGs8so1Os5+/PD37OvrAvIE/3osIoBRYVwDfNMaEHKE8GWPBReRHfNWpySGXtYTIDs7DQl/cf22f9uA3/w2z5kKzE0WDjyNhDph4fdnnqEMrcqBnqEbnTxDCjHfm3iXbPitiq4eD72Ha8br2XkRpPyGOyayeTvFJuIcMpCsYQoPikCnCl06nLKtPyB/kEcZBjObvJQLQ/NTEjhgtxm4kXBnSKqm/n4z0ROGT+PReYnAXFqbBf6/vCI0EaDtEpcmTVAmm9jUOIEYzCaFM4QwjL5KyxvGfw0IjjQ7245bWBAIVyxyr9H+mNy5OxDP0rorUoag4Yb5FzO2avXDgz3J+WrKOGEYBnddf0EW4XAS7/BdND0bQ8wF9E8xK0+3fOL52o0A9rpxGiLK31ECNQB2Bj4mq2ELq0nyUD5GMKj1yLn2s9boXbg89/E7lKqECNmXYZzsc/PiRmQnJOadMAc1za9gBlPueIbRC1ktzH9+obOW9fRKtY/xYFgjn+vkM3Jq9dHj+75EFt6atLk31tuEyMSgLCRmB6FhvQmNx3aaEova+ssNRmHYgNLwPNwYmWwcxtsAmUEAkIZbDc45Bk49QzBM4nm490TUnwvIMqTcRTmHBkfvfrm9cx4Pm14ljmGgRmgvrJbT7HH6/ye9iNOP81TnFhQbfr30mwwvhOq6Rp/PnS/XEOn3A3hKYH6HCgXYaT3kXwZJfCRZ7EMjKKbkbcFPMe+knJzLrMMFspJFvlkFPzxfQvx/mLk0waLUYOWPSexlpcfDZ/BWOBYX0Jbg5kr0TQX9FPoQzuhCfaev0/B8GyXBE3Rc+Kbju1Iq+bZANCKdF2Tn8UkCpQPzEir7+0Z1SYdEv54B2XopCWO+mQ6Wk5KSF/Z3VjnYVojWlmLVwhx6RWqG970a4NpuV0HQR3rLUpmbb6yY13r4M1NtLzrJ9xmIfZSbWD8apLtRreml5YNJpbEoJ/UWqJhP8XpHdCL1MjtqU0Hkkq+ReVsWFrYCTwqfskjXXOPJtZTtjo033U6dt/GR6x53QstLmMBtbSalB7WIR1s/U54aN04k3vT4SsWbknvJzJAvR+Niev4Slq6axG0ccew4xp2fiTdCZ+1D4nKHW3PqIKyNlPgFVYH2e8tlyWieo0mseWotxmKGWXoZMIjJ3665BpOqxsflbUufhXJIqIxzzaOacQwpV6ve8n5zSANXFIIIS7d3B7fueN7EXK4X4uyFrkSrjyTEjTWpibRR+zk1L2qBPed2NHsf5y/RZLf3pHclSgWOVJfX0pp0dyNT8Qlo1iNXifuimLODEE7alCkYSolMDW7k49UDh49cjZpL87VQLXQDNQW5ZfL3nFzXDNSapOxz9MIyR8k8pLVGR4dfo2n5V5Tdj0usnyUzBzP2XiD842AojZlUeQwNR9TddCVw5lei2QCHZA1udxArJSCQiFhJJsRTPOrId1HM7g7wXoilOoB62ogzGr5JGAOuFNeDatkrMRUsRKwMAEVtnBY9pNhGTlSxK/fXUfhzU/gzxuc1FqGYIwFAF5Y6kFIA0nss4zUBif3n38/y/T7f0IRrLZKYmtyYPEPhIyJONpAuBUeylTw9zA/zqmWbp8SseRhKWN7GNTDmJwhlThbXjTd6eoGiQvIQvNQi2A2QzYio0N05Q2SlYtbwTtSpxCy69zfp9zFONfLZgBSZraBArpxyTaZFldQzHZNaTFxdlMTGC3t6gH4qweJqNB3sP+e1p6M2X1SQsKR+z3Y9SJmswl70ephYo7G/QYS1eWrCOm+KAd42WHdK6Xbsw43obkO8lUQT4awuHHGvlQuwpRNoDNLfd11Mi23Ild2LVXXmFCKebV9K9FVSw25ANtjyJ2VasIZbqWNGsCbTkJx9IVzcGOUEhQSGehm20hH1wFHsQzXhgx3YeNucnV2jPRyLNxkM97Mb1SM4QSgwoPyD1LGebaZtvmRPtdrPpAhHlZQ6C0vVzXzt1p1ZXr1mmUBSuu29NOuCTz8Jr3qrgS062fBWgTvzuVVVUW0VfizmAAbMtyBxk4PaKe1iFZrnb90FyB8vf4QQr79Zi8lz5/2UVgVVDkqAR5XKK1525RtvAcmsZt7HG+oO6PcFEnUTKo5S2Vka26Mq4h7tp2BDkqRR1CVDSGMQj3enWUBAhqY8g0KD7sKMhp4KOnfW67qRhKZh4Q5GNL7x8KRYO/Bcuip9RD4AskS1RHSfTmhT+WEqp6PL6f06Z7SSyUvoiSIGg77HUBGh9b7fy1lIgdD/vC9ziBoyAt0xNyDtsIk1xTSGljNmlE9l+GuZT9z084uPNveQvU2hrKwU5hlc4R4J2P6MovCcSc/u8yw/RKewlPI18JPAGK9bTZ27sRMJlt7xL63K+mFIcgZAwCRNghCnnosgRTZUIIzHI/UCleFSzGQwxmMDmUGSyAmR3lbAGm1PL3tYlMLqWigtwEg+gEfaA4oFM4a+TPl2SasQ10C7roIXrdn6wX9XTh33Sp6uLNVLpeo+JpWImrV6GPQQS2MFBYHZqu9evs2PQ+3nTdoTmeDzYefSs7F7tbgztW2da2KA6Sk5I8RJ+pgK9xvW92qTJEpp+UaxxidFusfXNFvu86cwLFv9/ofsXd/+0rn9Wro93yoHpjlgw09f6yXUjabhvcETrkDkEJfIj3nqUOxy/B+4f1NRV19m11d2zj03K9otWMj3oEcwFpt07JrkdwRWK16y+KwfqF+3+GT55FT9G9xiYoTbT5VzQK/NV65fQItZpliTZtbtk3BthjcDb/aDpxzbfFGWRLTgGbev/K8Y6cOMa+eDauLF3LerNHC8J+IjPwb8aQosOt1hCxzlV9ze6Ws0159PPW8gS1xt+9fG95LZzJ4z5ZL+sOOep2o8loaNaEGoOLPkKo+t3G9P25a938+57a16g2+K/4wqVXtLH39TlzoBs3ZmVJ817G/7+ccnrOJSZ1WtbISB2c7QtXlqm2ga1Wti765u2mPa5Db028ypJkNZSnU5L40s31pZvvSzPbRmtmMTRjYv/ZResdu0STyabSIDOoF6bcRZSGIOFG1a9z8F7GUGcc=)

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

Comment: It's unknown what's wrong in your case. If you did everything correctly, it's supposed to work. You truncated the snippets that could contain the mistakes. If code is not relevant, it's not needed in the question. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. If you're unsure if you provided enough code to reproduce the problem, consider creating a demo that can do it

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks for your response. I edited my question with all code, and i can´t to build a demo, because neither will run... I don´t know wich it´s my problem

Comment: I see no problem, there are common mistakes that could led to this but none so far. You're not using `registers` from useNregister, it's supposed to be used instead of registerData, that's how composables differ from regular helper functions. Any way, it should work the way it was done, getRegisters returns correct data. You can provide a demo by removing unnecessary parts like api calls. Most questions are solved on their own this way, actually.  Btw it accepts incorrect param, it treats param_search as a value but it's a ref. `:key='item'` doesn't look good, should be `:key='item.id'

Comment: @EstusFlask i updated my question with SFC, but i don´t know to do for run. It´s a example that how is all my structure with all my code. I change register_data to register and i try, but same problem

Comment: I don't see a problem that could explain the problem with the table. It's not reproducible by somebody else. You could remove forms, axios calls, etc, to the point it can be made a workable demo. You shouldn't just replace it, if you use `registers` then this `registers.value = await getRegisters(` is unnecessary, should be `await getRegisters(`

Comment: @EstusFlask i change my SFC, deleting ```registerData.value = await getRegisters``` and return directly registers and pass to my table ```registers``` but same problem... i don´t understand

Comment: As I said, it's correct this way but it was supposed to be workable the original way too, this means that the problem is somewhere else. Possibly your understanding of correct api response differs from a needed one or else, that's why a reproducible example is necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function useNregister(){
    var registers = ref()

    //.....
    //.......
return{
     getRegisters,
     registers,
     /*deleteCall,
     queryForKeywords,
     getResults,
     getItems*/
}
```

You return registers, but when it returns it has no value because it expects to get a value when the asynchronous code of axios finishes. The only valid return is getRegisters whitch can used by the caller.

Comment: thanks for your response, but in my action button i´m calling get register and assing result to ```variable.value```

Comment: This is not the issue here, this is exactly the problem that ref pattern addresses. It's very common for composables to return reactive value