# not receive data in my another component vuejs 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

i´m trying to send data to my another component when i clicked on button. i can show perfectly my data in my first component:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="item in registers" :key="item.id">
       {{ registers }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

result it´s:

```
[ { "id": 895, "name": "Aguilera Muriel Fatimas", "address": "CALLE CALLEJAS, 8", 
.......
```

To build my app i´m using composition API and composables.

this array data it´s in `formTelemarketing.vue` that this component have a form. When clicked my button call to function in composable that call API in Laravel. To call function of my composable, i´m doing:

```
const fetchData = async (param_search) => {
                address = document.getElementById("address").value
                if( address != "" ) {
                    param_search["parameter"] = "address";
                    param_search["value"] = address;
                }

                city = document.getElementById("city").value
                if( city != "" ) {
                    param_search["parameter"] = "city";
                    param_search["value"] = city;
                }

                cp = document.getElementById("postal_code").value
                if( cp != "" ) {
                    param_search["parameter"] = "cp";
                    param_search["value"] = cp
                }

                registers.value = await getRegisters(toRef(param_search,'param_search'))
            }

return {
    fetchData,
    registers,
}
```

in my button i´m calling to `fetchData`

```
<button class="btn btn-dark" @click="fetchData">Buscar registros</button>
```

and register it´s i want i send it to my table component for this i´m trying:

```
const registers = ref([]);

<div id="app5">
    <nAsignedCalls :registers="registers"></nAsignedCalls>
</div>
```

and in my `nAsignedCalls` component y have a props:

```
export default {
        name: 'nAsignedCalls',    
        
        props: ['registers'],

        setup(props) {
            const { deleteCalls, queryForKeywords, getResults, getItems } = useNregister() 
            //const registers = ref(props.registers); ***** i trayed with this also.... *****
```

Also i tryed with:

```
setup(props) {
            const { deleteCalls, queryForKeywords, getResults, getItems } = useNregister() 
            const registers = ref(props.registers);
```

And `return registers` but i have same result. Also i tryed with:

```
props: { 
            registers: {
                type: Array,
                //default: () => ([])
            } 
        },
```

same result...

in my table component i have this to try show if my data it´s arrived.

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="item in registers" :key="item.id">
            {{ registers }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

but always it´s empty... in my `formTelemarketing` all it´s ok, but if i send it data... anything i´m doing wrong that i can´t pass data.

[SFC EXAMPLE](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

**EDIT**
I continue with this problem and i decided set a fixed data in my ref and check if my data arrive to my table. Yes, my data it´s arriving. But it´s strange what it does.

```
<template v-for="item in dataRegisters">
```

with this, my table it´s empty, only i can show my rows:

[image]

but if i use `dataRegisters.id` for example in all row repeat id. When i show my object i can show all data ok:

```
{ "address": "CALLE CALLEJAS, 8", "city": "PURULLENA", "cp": "18519", "created_at": "null", "id": "895", "mobile_phone": "null", "name": "Aguilera Muriel Fatimas", "phone": "958.690.236", "province": "GRANADA", "source": "", "updated_at": "2021-11-05T07:35:30.000000Z" }
```

i´m using

```
const registers = reactive({"address":"CALLE CALLEJAS, 8",
          "city":"PURULLENA",
          "cp":"18519",
          "created_at": "null",
          "id":"895",
          "mobile_phone":"null",
          "name":"Aguilera Muriel Fatimas",
          "phone":"958.690.236",
          "province":"GRANADA",
          "source":"",
        "updated_at":"2021-11-05T07:35:30.000000Z"})
```

to send data to my table because my data it´s a object.

Also i can show that my problem come from API. This it´s my code in my controller API laravel:

```
/**
     * FUNCTION TO RETURN REGISTER
     */
    public function getRegister($parameter, $value){
        try{
            
            if($parameter == 'address'){
                return ListingResource::collection(Listing::where('address', '=', $value)->all());
            }else if($parameter == 'city'){
                return ListingResource::collection(Listing::where('city', '=', $value)->get());
            }else if($parameter == 'cp'){
                return ListingResource::collection(Listing::where('cp', '=', $value)->get());
            }
        }catch(Exception $e){
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

and resource return:

```
class ListingResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable|\JsonSerializable
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

all return:

```
data: 
[{id: 895, name: "Aguilera Muriel Fatimas", address: "CALLE CALLEJAS, 
   8", province: "GRANADA",…},…]
[0 … 99]
0: 
{id: 895, name: "Aguilera Muriel Fatimas", address: "CALLE CALLEJAS, 8", 
 province: "GRANADA",…}
```

Comment: It's the same as in the previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75904883/fill-table-with-vue-js-3-and-composition-api . There are no obvious problems in these snippets, it's supposed to work (besides `const registers = ref(props.registers)` things, shouldn't be done, it can potentially cause exactly this problem) . You need a reproducible demo.

Comment: @EstusFlask i´m sorry for this new question, but i can´t solve my problem i don´t know that i´m doing wrong... I updated my question with SFC, but neither i can´t run it... I think that my problem it´s when i send data to my table component, but i don´t know where.

Comment: I see no possibility for it to update data in a parent and not a child. It should work the way you did it in the last SFC. I already posted a comment, it's still applicable. "As I said, it's correct this way but it was supposed to be workable the original way too, this means that the problem is somewhere else. Possibly your understanding of correct api response differs from a needed one or else, that's why a reproducible example is necessary here."

Comment: Currently the question is against SO rules because the problem cannot be reproduced by users. The work needs to be done on your side, like replacing api requests with dummy data, etc. "in my formTelemarketing all it´s ok" - this is not confirmed, that's the point

Comment: @EstusFlask i´m sorry for all my mistakes and to be noob, but i can´t to build runable SFC. i change it with delete axios petition and including array data with same data from my API assign to my ref and return it... maybe you can check now if you show anything that to do not run my script... I don´t know that to do yet

Comment: @EstusFlask in my script i changed my axios post to get, sending to my route any parameters, if my app not run for this... but same problem i can show all my data in console.log() but i can´t fill my table. I think that my variable it´s not updated in execution time....

Comment: In your mocked response `data` is an object but you're treating `registers` as an array. You need to eliminate the possibility of such mistakes in order to narrow down the problem. "my variable it´s not updated in execution time" - this shouldn't be a problem if vue reactivity works correctly, and currently it looks like it is, I don't see any scenarios here that could cause reactivity problems

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks for your time and help. i updated my question with new checks and new results that delimit my errors

Comment: The question doesn't need PHP, you need to narrow down the problem to either front or back end. You can see api response in devtools and copy it to mocked data if it conforms your expectations. Any way, I don't see how I can help at this point. I'm quite sure the problem can be debugged in a couple of minutes because there are only a few points of failure, but this can be done only on your side. Again, posting unconstructive questions that that need a reproduction but can't be reproduced by everyone else is against SO rules because this wastes everyone's time, hence the requirement for MCVE

Comment: That the table renders multiple rows could mean that data is rendered and there are layout problems, but again, can be verified on your side